# How to Reduce the size of date Picker control on view iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am working on Date Picker  and facing a problem of customizing the size .How to reduce the size for date picker  for example  height.

Comment: If somebody needs to do this now, you can set .transform property and for example use CGAffineTransformScale

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the iOS standard controls, like the date picker, have very limited customization options available. I do not believe, for example, that you can change the height. You could develop your own date picker control (if you wanted it to look like a little calendar, for example, you would have to do that anyway). But consider some of the advantages of using the standard control exactly as it is:

1. Less work than writing your own
2. Already familiar to most iOS users so there won't be usability issues
3. Very polished look and feel (for example, animations and sound effects)
4. Sizing and dimensions are already tested to work well for a touch interface

And so on.

Comment: You could try Kal (https://github.com/klazuka/Kal), an open-source implementation of the iOS calendar control.

Answer (score 0):

Gene says correctly ,

Use standerd controls if you have any problem such as covering your control by the date picker view then resize your view and animate the view(change y coordinate for the view).

May this help you to short out your problem.

Comment: I need implement custom date picker.This date picker is sample download pic. But i am not getting any clear idea  about custom date picker . if any tutorial related custom date picker/ sample . to implement.  
http://downloads.ziddu.com/downloadfile/12647925/2.png.html

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution here. You can make it look smaller by using views on top of it. If it's the view you want to customize then you can copy everything, throw it on photoshop, redraw it and then throw your new "customized view" on top of the datePicker. Many developers are doing that actually with the standard picker. It takes a couple more programming lines to do that but you can make it look great with some visual effort... Just a suggestion.

Comment: Hi Farini - could you elaborate a little more as I'm not clear entirely what you mean - but it sounds very intriguing.